# Aurelia Windows Authentication - Post 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, aurelia, windows-authentication

I'm totally stuck on implementing Windows authentication for one of my .NET Core apps that uses Aurelia for client side.

The Aurelia application is hosted on **port:9000** and the .NET WebAPI is hosted on **port:9001**.

The idea is to serve static pages from my .NET app once the app is published but now in development I use **port:9000** because of the BrowserSync provided by Aurelia.

When I use **port:9000** it's all fine and dandy and I have no issues posting or getting.

If I switch to **port:9001** I can still get but not post. Posting results in `401 Unauthorized`.

If we look at the headers for **port:9000** requests..

**Get(success):**

[image]

**Post(failed):**

[image]

You can see that there are multiple headers missing in the post for some reasons, most importantly the authentication cookie..

**Base-Repo.js**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {AppSettings} from '../infrastructure/app-settings';

@inject(HttpClient, AppSettings)

export class BaseRepo {
    constructor(http, appSettings) {
        http.configure(config => {
            config
                .withDefaults({
                    credentials: 'include',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .withInterceptor({
                    request(request) {
                        console.log(`Requesting ${request.method} ${request.url}`);
                        return request;
                    },
                    response(response) {
                        console.log(`Received ${response.status} ${response.url}`);
                        return response;
                    }
                })
        });

        this.http = http;
        this.baseUrl = appSettings.api;
    }

    get(url) {
        console.log('BaseRepo(get): ' + url);
        return this.http.fetch(this.baseUrl + url)
            .then(response => { return response.json(); })
            .then(data => { return data; });
    }

    post(url, data) {
        console.log('BaseRepo(post): ' + url, data);
        return this.http.fetch(this.baseUrl + url, {
            method: 'post',
            body: json(data)
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => { return data; });
    }
}
```

Why is GET working but not POST when using BrowserSync port?

**Edit 1**

**Post(success) for port:9001:**

[image]

**Edit 2**
Console message post error:

> OPTIONS `http://localhost:9001/api/MYURLS 401 (Unauthorized)`
>
> Fetch API cannot load
>   http://localhost:9001/api/MYURLS.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401. If an opaque response
>   serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
>   resource with CORS disabled.

**Edit 3**

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
            });

            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddMvc();

            services.InjectWebServices();

            services.AddOptions();

            //call this in case you need aspnet-user-authtype/aspnet-user-identity
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseDefaultFiles();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //add NLog to ASP.NET Core
            loggerFactory.AddNLog();

            //add NLog.Web
            app.AddNLogWeb();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I enabled "Enable Anonymous Authentication" in project properties and voila...

Before I only had "Enable Windows Authenticaiton" enabled, now both ports work!

When application is deployed this wont be enabled anyway because by then I will use the real IIS.

**Update 1**

After upgrading to .net core 2.0 I was no longer able to enable both Windows Authentication and Anonymous Authentication.
After some research I found out you have to add:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

in your startup.cs in order for it to work.

More info can be found in [comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth) section and [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x#windows-authentication-httpsys--iisintegration).

**Update 2**

You need **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication** package for authentication builder.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) in your ASP.NET Core project. There's information on how to do this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors.

You need to call `AddCors` in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddCors();
```

And then `UseCors` in `Configure`:

```
// Shows UseCors with CorsPolicyBuilder.
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com"));
```

When you're using port 9000, you're on a different origin to the API, but with 9001, you're on the same origin and therefore CORS will not apply.

The OPTIONS requests are known as "preflighting". There's more information on those here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests.

Comment: It can't be a problem with CORS. I'm already allowing all origins please see my last update

Comment: Did you also call `AddCors` on `IServiceCollection` and ensure that `UseCors` is **above** `UseMvc`?

Comment: Also tried same implementation as this: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas